# Значение передаваемое через bundle равно null

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-bundle

Мне необходимо передать данные из активити в фрагмент. Для примера я решил изменить название кнопки. Я использую `Bundle`. Но bundle передаёт пустое значение.
С чем может быть связано такое поведение ?

Код из Активити.

```
//Фраг
m_recept_frag frag = new m_recept_frag();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String s = "Test";
bundle.putString("key", s);
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Код из Фрагмента.

```
if (bundle != null) {
    String i = bundle.getString("key");
    name_rec1.setText(i);
}
else {
    name_rec1.setText("Пустое значение");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код фрагмента.

```
public class m_recept_frag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        m_recept_view mreceptview = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(m_recept_view.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_recept, container, false);

        Button spisok_rec = root.findViewById(R.id.Spis_rec);
        spisok_rec.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button add_rec = root.findViewById(R.id.Add_rec);
        add_rec.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Rec
        Button name_rec1 = root.findViewById(R.id.name_rec1);
    name_rec1.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Получение данных
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
             String i = bundle.getString("key");
            name_rec1.setText(i);
        }
        else {
            name_rec1.setText("Пустое значение");
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.Spis_rec:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),  Spisok_recept.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.Add_rec:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Recept_add.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Полный код `ActivityMain`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    public static ReceptDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Установка темы без родного бара + фуллскрин
        setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Инициализация цвета иконок меню
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_main, R.id.nav_recept, R.id.nav_ingred, R.id.nav_setting)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), ReceptDatabase.class, "Recept").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        //Фрагмент
        m_recept_frag frag = new m_recept_frag();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String s = "Test";
        bundle.putString("key", s);
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите код фрагмента функции где вы получаете bundle, с виду вроде все нормально

Comment: Судя по коду, можно сделать предложение, что это не Bundle передаёт пустое значение, а сама переменная `bundle` равна null.

Comment: @Andrew Добавил полный код фрагмента.

Comment: @НиктаЗемлин, вам же писали в прошлой теме, чтобы вы скинули код FragmentManager и FragmentTransaction, где вы передаете фрагмент

Comment: @danilshik Я использую уже готовый шаблон от студии NavigationDrawer в котором не используется FragmentManager

Comment: @НиктаЗемлин Navigation Library? Скиньте код Activity

Comment: @danilshik Добавил в описании вопроса полный код ActivityMain.

Comment: @НиктаЗемлин ну так вы используете Navigation Library, там параметры передаются через graph вроде

Comment: `m_recept_frag frag = new m_recept_frag();` Вы создаете __новый__ фрагмент, передаете туда бандл, сборщик мусора уничтожает фрагмент. Вам нужно обратиться к уже существующему фрагменту, никаких `new`

Comment: @НиктаЗемлин https://teletype.in/@skillbranch/HyYKu-oqS